# Coarea-like formula for BV functions (not their derivative)

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^N$ and $f \in BV(\Omega)$. The coarea formula states that

$$Df = \int_{\mathbb R} D \chi_{\{f >h\}} \,  dh.$$

Unfortunately, the formula 
$$f = \int_{\mathbb R}  \chi_{\{f >h\}} \,  dh$$
does not hold. But is an analogous one true? That is, can we write in some way $f$ as integral of characteristic functions of level sets?

Comment: What's wrong with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_cake_representation ?

Comment: @WillieWong That sounds great. How can it be generalized if $f$ is not necessarily non-negative?

Comment: Write $f = f_+ - f_-$?

Comment: @WillieWong In that case get $f(x)=\int _{0}^{\infty }1_{L(f,t)}(x)\,dt + \int _{\infty}^{0}1_{E(f,t)}(x)\,dt,$ where  $L(f,t)=\{y\in {\mathbb  {R}}^{n}|f_+(y)\geq t\}$ and $E(f,t)=\{y\in {\mathbb  {R}}^{n}|f_-(y)\geq t\}$. Can it be written in a better way as an integral over $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Riku One could as an analogous question for complex valued functions (or for vector valued ones). So maybe you are looking for something like $f = \int_0^\infty \frac{f}{|f|} \chi_{\{|f|>t\}} \, dt$? (Of course we should define $\frac{f}{|f|}=0$ whenever $|f|=0$.)